# Currency Symbol Display Is Incorrect

Tags: c#, server

The currency symbol and currency format for this language code is displaying incorrectly when called through C# on a server.

ms-MY (Malay - Malaysian)

The language display on the control panel on the server has the currency symbol set to RM. While debugging the C# code, it has the currency code set to R.

I wrote up a mini console program locally to display the currency symbol for ms-MY and it shows up as RM.

If I change the formatting on the server. The code doesn't pick up the changes. Anyone knows if there are weird server caches or another place that language settings are stored?

I've checked the language registry key between the server and my local machine and they are the same. I tried recycling the application pool and it still doesn't work.

Pseudo Code on the server

```
foreach (CultureInfo c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures))
{
    if (c.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName != "IVL")
    {
        r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID);
        if (r.ISOCurrencySymbol == isoCurrencyCode)
        {
            ci = c;
            FoundCode = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Mini Console Code for testing locally.

```
decimal amount = 179835.00M ;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ms-my")));
```

Note when I add this to the watcher on the server code: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ms-my"). The currency format display as R. But if I look at the watcher on my local console code nothing related to the server, it's set to RM

Comment: Could you please supply code to explain better what your issue is, and also what you have already tried?

Comment: Supply the "mini console" program code so we can replicate it ourselves.

Comment: What do you mean with "server" what are you using for communication? ASP? WebApi? WCF? Based on you communication layer, your thread culture might be set to the client culture.

Comment: When I say "server" I mean the code that is being executed on the "server" not my local machine. I assumed the CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures would grabbed the Region/Languages that are installed on the server. So whatever is on the list of languages under Control Panel -> Region/Language